# how to calculate a new column after grouping with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to calculate Revenue per load, after grouping by "Team" for my Shiny Dashboard. I am being told I have an invalid 'type' (character) of argument

I have tried changing how the summarise function is formatted. It does not work in the console, so I have removed the Shiny portions of the code.

```
 August <- data.frame("Revenue" = c(10,20,30,40), "Volume" = c(2,4,5,7), 
 "Team" = c("Blue","Green","Gold","Purple"))


  x <-   August %>% group_by(Team) %>% summarise(Revenue = sum(Revenue)) / 
 August %>% group_by(Team) %>% summarise(Volume = sum(volume)) %>%
```

"Error: invalid 'type' (character) of argument"
this shows up instead of the bar graph

Comment: Change this part `summarise(sum(volume))` to `summarise(Volume=sum(volume))`, it looks like you are referring to this in the `ggplot` call as `Volume`.

Comment: Are you sure about `August %>% group_by(Team) %>% summarise(Revenue = sum(Revenue)) / 
 August %>% group_by(Team) %>% summarise(sum(volume))`, maybe you're looking for `August %>% group_by(Team) %>% summarise(Rev = sum(Revenue)/sum(Volume))%>%ggplot(data = ., aes(x=Team, y=Rev , fill = factor(Team))) + ...`

Comment: @r2evans it does not work on the console

Comment: @A.Suliman I tried that before. it did not work. Maybe i Need to create a column called revenue per load in the dataframe first?

Comment: Is that supposed to be `data.frame` (with a dot), or is there some function `dataframe`?

Comment: @Rob just it's not possible to divide two complete chains. you can't do something like `August %>% group_by(Team) %>% summarise(Revenue = sum(Revenue)) ->a;August %>% group_by(Team) %>% summarise(Volume = sum(Volume)) -> b;` then `a/b`

Comment: A.Suliman, that *can* work ... it's unconventional, perhaps, and (imo) hard to read/troubleshoot, but it can work.

Comment: @r2evans sorry, it is `data.frame`

Comment: @r2evans given a and b are dividable, or you can divide a by b

Comment: One column of your frame is either `factor` (as you've provided here) or `character` (as suggested in the error, though not exactly right). Perhaps `August %>% group_by(Team) %>% summarise(Revenue = sum(Revenue), Volume = sum(Volume))`?

Comment: @A.Suliman should I calculate `a` and `b` outside my `shinyServer` function and then insert them back in or do all of that within `shinyServer`?

Comment: @A.Suliman, I'm referring to the division of two chains: it *is* possible: `tibble(a='a', b=1) %>% tally() / tibble(a='a', b=1) %>% tally()` works without error. One problem is that Rob is trying to divide non-numeric columns, not that there are chains being divided.

Comment: @r2evans that worked! how do I show that you answered it? haha

Comment: @Rob `server <- function(input,output){
output$team.rpl <- renderPlot({
August %>% group_by(Team) %>% summarise(Revenue = sum(Revenue)/sum(Volume)) %>%
ggplot(data = ., aes(x=Team, y=Revenue , fill = factor(Team))) + 
geom_bar(position = "dodge",stat = "sum") +
ylab("Revenue per Load")+ xlab("Team") + theme(legend.position = "none" , plot.title = 
element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"))+
ggtitle("Revenue per Load by Team") + labs(fill = "Team") + 
scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("Blue","Gold","Green","Purple"), values = c("blue","gold","green","purple"))})
}`, should work fine.

Comment: G.Grothendieck beat me to the punch, accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarize the `Revenue` and `Volume` and then take their ratio.  Note that `summarise` proceeds from left to right so that after `Revenue` and `Volume` have been defined in the `summarise` statement the references in the `RevByVol` definition to them refers to these new definitions and not to the original unsummarized versions.

```
August %>% 
  group_by(Team) %>% 
  summarise(Revenue = sum(Revenue), 
    Volume = sum(Volume), 
    RevByVol = Revenue / Volume) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Team   Revenue Volume RevByVol
  <fct>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Blue        10      2     5   
2 Gold        30      5     6   
3 Green       20      4     5   
4 Purple      40      7     5.71
```